# Using proc_open function in PHP

Tags: php, tcl

I am trying to execute a TCL script from PHP. I am using PHP's proc_open for the communication .But I am unable to get the result from the tcl script .
Can someone go through the code and let me know where I am going wrong ?

PHP code

```
<?php
$app = 'tclsh84.exe';

$spec = array(array("pipe", "r"), array("pipe", "w"), array("pipe", "w"));

$process = proc_open($app, $spec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) 
{

    fwrite($pipes[0], 'source sum.tcl ');
    fwrite($pipes[0], 'tclsh test.tcl ');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

  echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[1]);

 //   echo fread($pipes[1],1024).'<hr>';


   proc_close($process);
}
?>


//sum.tcl 
proc sum {arg1 arg2} {
    set x [expr {$arg1 + $arg2}];
    return $x
}

//test.tcl
puts " the sum is [sum 10 9 ] "
```

Comment: What do you see on the error pipe?

Comment: "tclsh" is not a Tcl command.  Did you mean "source test.tcl"?

Comment: I don't see any error . I just get a blank page on the browser. tclsh is a command , it is used to execute a tcl file.

Comment: I know tclsh is a command. But it is not a command that tclsh84.exe understands (which is the $app of your $process). Also, what's the exit status from proc_close? What error messages can you read from $pipes[2]? You have a lot of debugging you should be doing yourself.

Comment: tclsh was creating a new child process .hence the script was not executing .I just sourced the file and called the proc from the same file

Comment: hey glen,
Could you look in to this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326499/how-to-make-fread-blocking-and-read-until-the-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing newlines to the application (`fwrite($pipes[0], "source sum.tcl\n")`), could that be the cause? Otherwise make sure to check all return values of your function calls. You should fail early, if the first fwrite() fails, for example.

Comment: I got this one. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Please post your answer here.